# Is EJB still alive?

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, ejb

Do you still use session or entity EJBs in your project? Why?

Answer (score 28, accepted):

EJB3 is a **vast** improvement over previous versions.  It's still *technically* the standard server-side implementation toolset for JavaEE and since it now has none of the previous baggage (thanks to annotations and Java Persistence), is quite usable and being deployed as we speak.  As one commenter noted, JBoss SEAM is based upon it.

EJB 3 is a viable alternative to Spring, and the two technologies may become more tightly related.  [this](http://java.dzone.com/articles/end-spring-vs-ejb-wars-sight) article details that Spring 3.0 will be compatible with EJB Lite (which I'm not sure what that is, exactly) and possibly be part of Java EE 6.

EJB is not going anywhere.

Comment: "*EJB is not going anywhere*". Hello from the future. Thanks for the laugh

Comment: OMG this brings me back lol.  EJB still seems to exist, but who knows how widely it is used, ibid SEAM.  I am VERY happy to have not had to use these technologies in a very long time

Answer (score 6):

We're working with EJB here and it works quite well with JBoss Seam and JSF, Faclets and MyFaces Trinidad. Good UI, Templating, AJAX and stable production 24/7 running on JBoss 4.2.

It's a good stack for business processes, workflows, messageing, webservices and ui control. Fast delivery of features, easy programming and stable ground based on entitybeans with mysql persistance.

I don't want to miss the featureset of EJB 3 for the tasks our product demands.

Answer (score 3):

See the overview of [new features in Java EE 6](http://www.theserverside.com/news/1363662/Java-EE-6-Overview).  EJB 3.1 and WebBeans 1.0 help make a Java EE 6 container environment become easier to use, similar to frameworks like Seam on Java EE 5 or Spring.  If you're familiar with Spring 3, [this article](http://www.javacodegeeks.com/2011/11/from-spring-to-java-ee-6.html) illustrates how Java EE has evolved to become a comparable framework.

Answer (score 2):

EJB is still there and growing up. There are many new features (SOAP/RESTful webservice, JPA entities, JAXB...) depend on it or at least reuse the philosophy of developing.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, but EJB were stupidly complex for most use cases. Very clever, but real overkill in most cases. Hence the lightweight approach taken now-a-days.

Justin

Comment: Only that over time most successful lightweight approaches become just as heavy weight as the technology they are supposed to replace.

Comment: EJB is one of those odd regressing cases where EJB3 is **far** simpler than previous versions.

Answer (score -2):

I've just started back to work on an EJB project. I didn't remember how heavy and hard was to work with this technology. It was luck when Spring, Hibernate and Maven came. Since then everything was different and much easier.

I always could see this technology was never used properly and was taken as a pattern that I never understood.

It was supposed you needed two containers and if it was possible one server for each container. One for Business(EJBs) and another one for Views(MVC). I never saw that.

Well, it's good to know that EBJ is upgrading.